# Parse composite json key

Tags: java, json, spring, jpa

I have a json like `{"xxx.Name-xxx-1111111":"100"}`
Where 1111111 is timestamp and 100 is value

I need to put timestamp and value to jpa and insert to database via spring.

How can I parse this string and put it to jpa?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few popular libraries that can map JSON to objects with types of your choosing.

Google's GSON is a good one and the usage is very simple: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson

**JSON to Object**

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
MyObject myObject = gson.fromJson(jsonString, MyObject.class)
```

That should get the json into the format that you want so that you can persist it.

Comment: thx, but more actual how to split keys on the go by mask and then map to object

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the given JSON string by using popular JSON libraries such as **Jackson** or **Gson** as follows.

First, **1111111** is not a valid `Timestamp` format, it should look like this {"xxx.Name-xxx-**2019-10-08 09:00:00**":"100"}.

Second, use **Jackson** API to parse the JSON string to get key and value fields.

Third, I assume the prefix of timestamp value is **xxx.Name-xxx-**, then you can retrieve it (says **2019-10-08 09:00:00**) by using `String.replace()`.

Sample code:

```
String jsonStr = "{\"xxx.Name-xxx-2019-10-08 09:00:00\":\"100\"}";

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
for (Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> it = mapper.readTree(jsonStr).fields(); it.hasNext();) {
    Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> field = it.next();
    String key = field.getKey();
    int value = field.getValue().asInt();
    System.out.println("key:       " + key);
    System.out.println("value:     " + value);

    Timestamp timestamp = Timestamp.valueOf(key.replace("xxx.Name-xxx-", ""));
    System.out.println("timestamp: " + timestamp);
}
```

Console output:

```
key:       xxx.Name-xxx-2019-10-08 09:00:00
value:     100
timestamp: 2019-10-08 09:00:00.0
```

Finally, I think you can directly use these two variables: `timestamp` and `value` for JPA.